# Original proof that orders eliminate deadlocks?

Tags: reference-request, concurrency, order-theory, ordering

A well-known approach to eliminate the possibility of a deadlock when accessing exclusive ressources is enforcing a partial (or total) order in which the ressources may be requested.

**Which publication initially introduced this method?**

Comment: Wikipedia claims that Dijkstra used this method in his solution of the [dining philosophers problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem), the algorithm in his "hirarchical ordering of sequential processes" paper from 1971, however, seems quite different from that. Also, neither Wikipedia nor the paper claim tat Dijkstra introduced that method.